# Is there any difference between the two implementation of the struct?

Tags: rust, lifetime

```
struct ImportantExcerpt<'a> {
    part: &'a str,
}

impl<'a> ImportantExcerpt<'a> {
    fn level(&'a self) -> i32 {
        3
    }
}
```

vs

```
struct ImportantExcerpt<'a> {
    part: &'a str,
}

impl<'a, 'b> ImportantExcerpt<'a> {
    fn level(self: &'b ImportantExcerpt<'a>) -> i32 {
        3
    }
}
```

Comment: You are asking if those are 100% _equivalent_, right? The lexical difference is quite obvious.

Comment: You are aware that neither should be used, right? The correct way is `fn level(&self)` or `fn level<'a>(&'a self)`.

Answer (score 1):

In the example below, your two versions of `level()` are `level_1()` and `level_2()`.
There is not really a difference since these functions return a *value*, not a reference, thus the subtleties about lifetime do not change anything: the returned value will live on its own.
These two versions are used in the example, and we cannot see any difference about lifetime constraints.
However, if we want to return a reference, as in `text_1()` to `text_4()`, then the lifetimes must be considered with attention.

`text_1()` is the immediate adaptation of `level_1()`.
The [`lifetime elision rules`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/lifetime-elision.html#lifetime-elision-in-functions) tell us that the lifetime of the resulting `&str` is that of the `self` parameter (`'a` explicitly given here).
(Note that I'm not certain if it makes sense to write the same lifetime for the structure itself and a reference to it; someone with a better knowledge of Rust than me could develop around that)
This means that the resulting `&str` must not live longer than the structure; this is shown as an error in the example.

`text_2()` is the immediate adaptation of `level_2()`.
The [`lifetime elision rules`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/lifetime-elision.html#lifetime-elision-in-functions) tell us that the lifetime of the resulting `&str` is that of the `self` parameter (`'b` explicitly given here).
Then, this is equivalent to `text_3()` and the consequence is the same as with `text_1()`.
This means that the resulting `&str` must not live longer than the structure; this is shown as an error in the example.

When it comes to `text_4()`, we explicitly provide a lifetime for the resulting `&str` which is different from the lifetime of the `self` reference.
This is actually the same lifetime used internally for `part` in the structure.
This means that the resulting `&str` must not live longer than the original string used to initialise `part`, but it is not at all linked to the structure itself; the example shows that it is still possible to use the resulting `&str` after the structure is dropped.

```rust
struct ImportantExcerpt<'a> {
    part: &'a str,
}

impl<'a, 'b> ImportantExcerpt<'a> {
    fn level_1(&'a self) -> i32 {
        3
    }
    fn text_1(&'a self) -> &str {
        self.part
    }
    fn level_2(self: &'b ImportantExcerpt<'a>) -> i32 {
        3
    }
    fn text_2(self: &'b ImportantExcerpt<'a>) -> &str {
        self.part
    }
    fn text_3(self: &'b ImportantExcerpt<'a>) -> &'b str {
        self.part
    }
    fn text_4(self: &'b ImportantExcerpt<'a>) -> &'a str {
        self.part
    }
}

fn main() {
    let f_txt = "first".to_owned();
    let f_out = {
        let ie = ImportantExcerpt {
            part: f_txt.as_str(),
        };
        // (ie.text_1(), ie.level_1()) // `ie` dropped here while still borrowed
        // (ie.text_2(), ie.level_1()) // `ie` dropped here while still borrowed
        // (ie.text_3(), ie.level_1()) // `ie` dropped here while still borrowed
        (ie.text_4(), ie.level_1()) // correct
    };
    println!("{:?}", f_out);

    let s_txt = "second".to_owned();
    let s_out = {
        let ie = ImportantExcerpt {
            part: s_txt.as_str(),
        };
        // (ie.text_1(), ie.level_2()) // `ie` dropped here while still borrowed
        // (ie.text_2(), ie.level_2()) // `ie` dropped here while still borrowed
        // (ie.text_3(), ie.level_2()) // `ie` dropped here while still borrowed
        (ie.text_4(), ie.level_2()) // correct
    };
    println!("{:?}", s_out);
}
/*
("first", 3)
("second", 3)
*/
```

Comment: The thing if you make (self: &'b ImportantExcept<'a>) is that you can't return Self with a lifetime of 'a, like so:

`fn lv(self: &'b ImportantExcept<'a>) -> &'a Self<'a> {self}`

But I don't think that it makes any sense since I don't think you can make a &'b ImportantExcept<'a> such as `'b: 'a` isn't true, therefore you can just `impl<'a, 'b>` and it will also compile.

Answer (score 1):

Here is code equivalent to your example with usage example ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3aba3d79e76d34ec7c71d2541dbb0fbf))

```rust
struct ImportantExcerpt<'a> {
    part: &'a str,
}

impl<'a> ImportantExcerpt<'a> {
    fn level1(self: &'a Self) -> i32 {
        3
    }

    fn level2<'b>(self: &'b Self) -> i32 {
        3
    }
}

fn main() {
    let string: &'static str = "string";
    let ie: ImportantExcerpt<'static> = ImportantExcerpt {part: string};
    dbg!(ie.level1());
    dbg!(ie.level2());
}
```

This compiles fine, but only because of a certain feature of rust, variance (see [reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/subtyping.html) and [rustnomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/nomicon/subtyping.html)). `ie` has type `ImportantExcerpt<'static>`, therefore you could think that level1 expects a static reference to `ie`. But before the function gets called, the type of `ie` changes to `ImportantExcerpt<'a>` where `'a` is a much more local lifetime, shorter than `'static`. This means that in this example, where owned values are returned, the functions have no difference. But more generally, there could be a difference if `ImportantExcerpt<'a>` is invariant (or contravariant) over `'a`. For example ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=421e42334462d2ff6d615c68fb557c95)):

```rust
use std::cell::Cell;

struct ImportantExcerpt<'a> {
    part: Cell<&'a str>,
}

impl<'a> ImportantExcerpt<'a> {
    fn level1(self: &'a Self) -> i32 {
        3
    }

    fn level2<'b>(self: &'b Self) -> i32 {
        3
    }
}

fn main() {
    let string: &'static str = "string";
    let ie: ImportantExcerpt<'static> = ImportantExcerpt {part: Cell::new(string)};
    dbg!(ie.level1());
    dbg!(ie.level2());
}
```

Here `dbg!(ie.level2())` compiles, but `dbg!(ie.level1())` fails with the error that `ie` doesn't live long enough. Here the conversion described above can't happen, so level1 expects a reference with the same lifetime as Self, which is `'static`.

In general I would recommend the second function, as it should work in more cases.